# No guarda datos en postgresql y laravel

Tags: laravel, postgresql, laravel-blade

Hola estoy haciendo un crud con laravel (ultima versión) y postgresql.
El problema es que no me guarda datos.
La base de datos esta conectada y ya hice una migración.

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{
    $user = new User;

    $user->nombres = $request->nombres;
    $user->apellido_paterno = $request->apellido_paterno;
    $user->apellido_materno = $request->apellido_materno;
    $user->rut = $request->rut;
    $user->telefono = $request->telefono;
    $user->email = $request->email;
    $user->status = $request->estado;
    $user->fecha_nacimiento = $request->fnacimiento;

    return redirect()->route('welcome')
    ->with('info', 'Usuario creado');
}
```

El formulario me manda a la pagina principal (que es lo correcto, pero con los datos del formulario en el link y no guarda nada mas)

```html
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.css"></head>

        <form action="{{route('store')}}" method="POST">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <form-group>
                        <label for="">Ingrese los nombres del usuario</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombres" required>
                    </form-group>
                    <form-group>
                        <label for="">Ingrese el apellido paterno</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="apellido_paterno" required>
                    </form-group>
                    <form-group>
                        <label for="">Ingrese el apellido materno</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="apellido_materno" required>
                    </form-group>
                    <form-group>
                            <label for="">Ingrese el email</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" required>
                    </form-group>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <form-group>
                        <label for="">Ingrese el rut del usuario</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="rut" required>
                    </form-group>
                    <form-group>
                            <label for="">Ingrese el telefono</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="telefono" required>
                        </form-group>
                        <form-group>
                             <label for="">Fecha de nacimiento</label>
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="fnacimiento" required>
                        </form-group>
                        <form-group>
                                <label for="">Ingrese el estado del usuario</label>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="estado" required>
                        </form-group>
                </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary mt-3 ml-3" type="submit">Guardar</button>
        </form>
```

Cualquier aporte es agradecido :P

Comment: Por qué te falta $user->save(); pues en tu código no lo tienes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final de tu código te hace falta indica que el objeto $user acceda al método save(); para que de esa manera se procese el alta quedando así

$user->save();

Es decir debe ir justo después de esta línea

$user->fecha_nacimiento = $request->fnacimiento;

Aquí tienes la [doc oficial](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#inserts) para consultar, ve al apartado de INSERT

Answer (score 3):

En ningún momento estas diciendole que guarde el modelo:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $user = new User;

    $user->nombres = $request->nombres;
    $user->apellido_paterno = $request->apellido_paterno;
    $user->apellido_materno = $request->apellido_materno;
    $user->rut = $request->rut;
    $user->telefono = $request->telefono;
    $user->email = $request->email;
    $user->status = $request->estado;
    $user->fecha_nacimiento = $request->fnacimiento;

    if ($user->save()) {

        return redirect()->route('welcome')
        ->with('info', 'Usuario creado');

    }

    // Algo salio mal
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Por si acaso, hay una forma distinta y hasta más sencilla en algunos casos para crear modelos, el método create(), el cual acepta un array como parámetro:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $user = User::create([
        'nombres' => $request->nombres,
        'apellido_paterno' => $request->apellido_paterno,
        // ...
    ]);

}
```